# Distinguish between `DataIntegrityViolationException` exceptions

Tags: java, spring

Currently, I've two different exceptions caught by `DataIntegrityViolationException` class:

1. duplicate keys.
2. Data truncation: Data too long for column.

---

My questions:

1. which cases I am missing?
2. How can I distinguish between different `DataIntegrityViolationException` exceptions?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe this will help you : http://www.baeldung.com/spring-dataIntegrityviolationexception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataIntegrityViolationException.html), `DataIntegrityViolationException` class is subclassed by `DuplicateKeyException` [class](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DuplicateKeyException.html). Here's what the documentation of `DuplicateKeyException` says:

> Exception thrown when an attempt to insert or update data results in
>   violation of an primary key or unique constraint.

So, if you want to distinguish between these two, you can provide two separate `catch` blocks and handle the exceptions accordingly, e.g.:

```
try{
    // Some operation
}catch (DuplicateKeyException dke){
    // Handle duplicate key
}catch (DataIntegrityViolationException dve){
    // Handle data integrity violation
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, this works only in JDBC, and not in JPA, due to some underlying Hibernate issues: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/16292